# Is there a desktop pager for Mac OS Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces

A desktop pager is a little program that sits in the corner or the dock, that allows me to switch desktops with a click, and drag windows between desktops.

Something like KDE had with kpager:

[image: KDE kpager]

Mission control is very nice, but it works better when you use a trackpad and not a mouse, and it can be quite an interruption. To move windows between desktops with key combos you need some acrobatics (click and hold titlebar, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⬅</kbd>). With a pager, you could just fling the icon to a different desktop.

Is there a desktop pager for Mac OS (Lion)?

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use a mouse efficiently with Mission Control. Set any corner, preferably bottom, as the hot corner (System Preferences > Mission Control > Hot Corners) for Mission Control. After that, it’s just simple drag and drop, and you can switch apps and desktops in under a sec, or 2 secs with a file being dragged.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a shareware, [totalspace](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/) which I found gives you the closest experience to unix-like pager.